# How can I see the output of a javascript function in plain text?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a server with a static html page, the page only consists of a textarea field with id="outputarea"

When I visit my page I can see in the console that the Javascript file is loaded and working.
I can see the output of the desired function when called in the console.

What I am currently doing is I visit my site with a selenium bot and execute this javascripyt

document.getElementById('outputarea').innerHTML = myFunction.whatever();

This shows me the output in text in the textarea.

So my question is this: How can I simple call for the javascript output by making a POST or GET request?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe **eval()** is useful to you, good luck!, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval